# Application hangs randomly on initialization in Windows phone 8 +

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, window

While launching application it gets stuck at splash screen randomly . I have tried resolution adjustment. Someone can suggest whole process of creating splash screen in windows can also help.

Comment: This is two questions. Edit it so that it includes your code and asks for help to debug the hang, or don't mention the hang and just as for an example on how to implement a splash screen.

Comment: While launching application it gets stuck at splash screen randomly . I have tried resolution adjustment.

Comment: <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="ICERTIS Contract Management" Square150x150Logo="Assets\SquareTile150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Description="WP8" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
        <m3:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="Assets\SquareTile71x71.png">
        </m3:DefaultTile>
<m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\Splashscreen.png" />                                                                                                                                                                      
      </m3:VisualElements>